# Multi select is returning NULL

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to make a simple form in reactive angular forms.
It has

- an email,
- a dropdown
- a multi select
- text area.

I am using 2 way binding. All are working fine except Multi select
Multi select is returning "NULL"

Here is the code

```
<div class="container">
    <h2 class="col-md-6 mx-auto my-auto"> form</h2>
    <form [formGroup]="dropdown">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Email address</label>
              <input formControlName="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="name@example.com">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" formControlName="single_select">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Example multiple select</label>
              <select multiple class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2" formControlName="multi_select">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Example textarea</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" formControlName="text_area"></textarea>
            </div>
    </form>
    {{dropdown.value | json}}
</div>
```

and TS code :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from "@angular/forms";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-dropdown',
  templateUrl: './dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dropdown.component.scss']
})
export class DropdownComponent implements OnInit {
  dropdown = new FormGroup({
    email : new FormControl(""),
    single_select : new FormControl(""),
    multi_select : new FormControl(""),
    text_area : new FormControl(""),
  });
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Result :
[image]

Comment: Could you please make a Stackblitz ? https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Your `<select>`'s options should have values declared with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I created a bug-fixed version on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rdtuat?file=src/app/app.component.html) for you.

You should add `[ngValue]` to your options ass follows:

```html
<select multiple class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2" formControlName="multi_select">
  <option [ngValue]="1">1</option>
  <option [ngValue]="2">2</option>
  <option [ngValue]="3">3</option>
  <option [ngValue]="4">4</option>
  <option [ngValue]="5">5</option>
</select>
```